What does this line above this note mean?
Above the note C5 at rehearsal mark (3rd measure below): is the line a part of the number 4 or part of the articulation (the dot on top of the note)?


What is the piece and who is the publisher? It looks like a tenuto (sustain) mark, but it's above a seeming staccato dot. I would like to know who published/edited the notation.

this is from a music book called The Legend of Zelda: Easy Piano and is the Song Title Theme from The Legend of Zelda you can see this part of it on https://www.amazon.co.uk/Legend-Zelda-Easy-Piano/dp/0739083244/ref=pd_vtp_h_pd_vtp_h_d_sccl_3/262-8771026-7891060?pd_rd_w=PBwgm&content-id=amzn1.sym.0024c6b5-da90-4821-b6c0-667e7c129058&pf_rd_p=0024c6b5-da90-4821-b6c0-667e7c129058&pf_rd_r=J1YHX7KG34283TPQ7PX9&pd_rd_wg=X4AuO&pd_rd_r=1aa65ac5-1637-44e8-9e24-e49755a45480&pd_rd_i=0739083244&psc=1

OK, Alfred is the publisher. Thanks.

It's also odd in bar 6 that there's a dotted  quaver, truncated by a staccato dot. Never seen that before - why not use a rest instead?

@Tim If you wanted to be ambiguous about how shortened the note is. Maybe it's an eighth, maybe a bit more, maybe a bit less. And on an instrument that can shape the decay envelope more than piano, it could also have implications that taper the note more than cut it off abrouptly.

@AndyBonner - except this is actually piano music.

@Tim In fact that is totally sensible notation. A rest would indicate an interruption in the phrase, while a staccato indication is only articulation.

@Lazy - can't really see the difference. A short pause, a breath, a rest...  it's all articulation.

Related: Articulation between staccato and full note length?, What do the dots and lines underneath these chords mean?

This means to separate the note, but not as sharply as with a full staccato. The tenuto line’s distance is just to avoid the staff line. It’s unrelated to the finger number.
An example of staccato-tenuto can be seen and heard in the below YouTube video of Kabalevsky's "Early Morning Exercises". The link is set to the beginning of the piece (1:42); the articulation first occurs at 2:20.




Source: Elaine Gould, Behind the Bars (p. 115).

@Jos thanks. I’ll see if there’s a good quote to add once I can get to my copy.

@GratefulDisciple Cool. Here's a YouTube video with score. The piece itself starts at 1:42, and the staccato-tenutos first appear at 2:20.

It's not part of the number.   Tenuto but staccato.   Full length, but a space between notes.   This has a specific meaning as a bowing instruction for string instruments.  For keyboard, you might well ask yourself 'so how is this different to 'play normally?', and it would be a good question! Might make a bit more sense used on a series of repeated notes.
It wasn't used on the very similar phrase two bars earlier.  A (very) subtle intended difference, or just sloppy notation?   Don't over-think it!

I also noticed the normal quaver in 4th bar and the (almost parallel) triplet quaver in 5th bar. It makes me think the subtle difference you picked up is probably intended.

What is the specific instruction for bowed instruments?

It's almost a contradiction in terms. The tenuto mark means hold the note for its full length, or leaving a slight separation with the following note. But then the staccato dot means play the note shorter than written.
However, when both are displayed, it lengthens the note. Ref. Elaine Gould, Behind Bars. Named portato, and more generally used when playing bowed instruments, not so easy to execute on piano, which this music is written for.

You say portato…

@BrianTHOMAS - it's so much more professional than 'spud'...

This mark means the composer doesn't trust you to play the piece nicely but still wants to micromanage you from beyond the grave.
It's worth noting that the line symbol - tenuto - does not mean smooth as is commonly asserted. It means slightly detached, because if you really wanted the notes as smooth as possible you would just slur them together - any professional classical musician will tell you this.

This seems half-irrelevant because the "tenuto with staccato", as in the question, means something substantially different from the regular tenuto you mention.
